# Vue unit testing: router path is always /

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

The router's `currentRoute.path` should be `/SignUpUser` as that is the page I import and it's route is `/SignUpUser`. However, the `path` turns out to be `root`.

This is the code:

```js
import SignUpUser from '@/components/SignForms/SignUpUser.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)


  it('does not route to root when sign up is interrupted because validations fail', async () => {
    let router = new VueRouter()
    const wrapper = mount(SignUpUser, {
      localVue,
      router,
    })

    console.log(router.currentRoute.path) // should be '/SignUpUser' but is '/'

    let usernameField = wrapper.findComponent('#username');
    usernameField.setValue('Avi')

    let submitBtn = wrapper.findComponent('button')

    await submitBtn.trigger('click');

    expect(router.currentRoute.path).toBe('/SignUpUser')
  })
```

Moreover, `expect(router.currentRoute.path).toBe('/SignUpUser')` fails because the path is still `/`. I am unsure what is happening and could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing a vue component, you have to configure everything: nothing from your actual app will be used.

That means your app `routes` configuration is not used here. So you are using a `VueRouter` without any routes configuration.

Just add a testing routes configuration (see [documentation](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html)):

```js
it('should redirect to /SignUpUser page', () => {
  const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: { template: 'Root' }
    },
    {
      path: '/SignUpUser',
      component: SignUpUser
    }
  ];

  let router = new VueRouter({ routes })
  router.push('/SignUpUser')

  // You are now on /SignUpUser

  const wrapper = mount(SignUpUser, {
    localVue,
    router,
  })
})
```

Note that it means your test will actually test a mocked Router, and it does not have much sense to check that on this route (that you set up yourself on the test) you mount this component.

Comment: But when I do `router.push('/SignUpUser')` I get this error: 

`
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/SignUpUser".".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
`
But `router.currentRoute.path` is `root` so I don't know what's happening.